# Given $A$, $A^{-1}$ can be expressed with: $A^{-1}=bA+dI$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

> Given the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
> -1 &3  &3 \\ 
>  3& -1 & 3\\ 
>  3& 3 & -1
> \end{pmatrix}$ then $A$ is invertible and $A^{-1}$ can be expressed with: $A^{-1}=bA+dI, b,d\in\mathbb R$

So it's easy to find that $|A|\neq 0$ so it's invertible, and from $AA^{-1}=I$ we get: $bx^2+dx-1= 0$ so if there are solutions to $bx^2+dx-1$ then $A^{-1}$ can be expressed with: $A^{-1}=bA+dI$ ? And there are obviously such $b,d$. Is that the correct approach?

Edit: characteristic polynomial of $A$: $(x+4)^2(x-5)$ how can you use it?

Comment: Find characteristic and minimal polynomial of $A$

Comment: I did that too but what does the characteristic polynomial has to do with $A^{-1}$? @kklm

Comment: It does help... What is minimal polynomial?

Comment: $(x+4)(x-5)= x^2 -x -20$ @kklm

Comment: $x^2-x-20=0$ i.e., $A^2-A-20=0$ i.e., $A(A-I)=20$ i.e., $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{20}(A-I)$

Comment: Oh I saw the $-20$ and thought that it doesn't fit the $-1$ from $bx^2+dx-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the minimal polynomial is as you said $x^2-x+20$. Then,
$$A^2-A-20I = 0$$
$$A(A-I) = 20I$$
$$\dots$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the minimal polynomial, which is $\;(x+4)(x-5)\;$:

$$0=(A+4I)(A-5I)=A^2-A-20I\implies 20I=A^2-A\implies A^{-1}=\frac1{20}\left(A-I\right)$$